# How to replace a string in a git alias

Tags: git, alias

Currently my organization uses ssh instead of https for Bitbucket. So when one does a

`git remote get-url origin`

It returns something like...

`git@bitbucket.org:myorg/myrepo.git`

I would like to create an alias that replaces the `git@bitbucket.org:` with `https://bitbucket.org/` to show what the https url would be.

Something like

`rr = "!f() { ref=$(git remote get-url origin); echo $ref; }; f"`

Except where the `echo $ref` is, it should do the above replacement instead. I just can't seem to find a good example of doing this sort of string replacement for a git alias function.

Comment: What you are trying to do has little to do with Git. Once you have the output of `git remote get-url origin`, pipe it through `sed` to make the replacement.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is more of a bash function. It's the sed part of this I cannot seem to get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the `:` and then the `git@`

```
git remote get-url origin|sed 's!:!/!g'| sed 's!^git@!https://!g'
```

Comment: That works! I actually think I got my original attempt working too with

`rr = "!f() { ref=$(git remote get-url origin); startcmd=$(echo \"$ref\" | sed -r 's|git@bitbucket.org:|https://bitbucket.org/|g'); echo $startcmd; }; f"`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but I marked Ôrel answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/72888991/222434

`rr = "!f() { ref=$(git remote get-url origin); startcmd=$(echo \"$ref\" | sed -r 's|git@bitbucket.org:|https://bitbucket.org/|g'); echo $startcmd; }; f"`